# Refactoring multiple ifs

Tags: python, django

My current code is this

```
class CounterFilters(TextChoices):
    publications_total = "publications-total"
    publications_free = "publications-free"
    publications_paid = "publications-paid"
    comments_total = "comments-total"
    votes_total = "voted-total"


class SomeView:

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        response_data = []
        if "fields" in request.query_params:
            fields = request.GET.getlist("fields")
            for field in fields:
                if field == CounterFilters.publications_total:
                    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.publications_total, "count": some_calculations1})
                if field == CounterFilters.publications_free:
                    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.publications_free, "count": some_calculations2})
                if field == CounterFilters.publications_paid:
                    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.publications_paid, "count": some_calculations3})
                if field == CounterFilters.comments_total:
                    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.comments_total, "count": some_calculations4})
                if field == CounterFilters.votes_total:
                    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.votes_total, "count": some_calculations5})
        return Response(response_data)
```

Based on get-param fields (which is list) I fill response_data data with some calculations, different for each CounterFilters.value .

I'm wondering, if there is a way to avoid this big amounts of ifs ?

Comment: From 3.10 upwards you have `switch case`, if not you could use `if elif` so after you've found a match you don't keep checking the other conditions.

Comment: @Daviid - but I need to check other conditions

Comment: Also you could just `response_data.append("type": field, , "count": some_calculations})`

Comment: How? inside an iteration of the for loop you can only match one if condition.

Comment: @Daviid Match-Case I presume

Comment: You can always use a dict to map field/choice and calculation and use it later to execute particular calculation

Comment: @journpy  If you mean to use match-case to check other conditions: Each case block automatically terminates when its code block completes. Python's match statement is a prettier way of if-elif-else statements. Not sure if you were thinking of a switch-case in php without breaks. Or I might just be interpreting wrong.

Comment: @Daviid was just pointing out the naming match-case in Python not switch case :)

Comment: @journpy -_- yeah, my bad. Can't fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift logic to the `TextChoices` function:

```
class CounterFilters(TextChoices):
    publications_total = 'publications-total'
    publications_free = 'publications-free'
    publications_paid = 'publications-paid'
    comments_total = 'comments-total'
    votes_total = 'voted-total'

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, f'get_{self.name}')(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_publications_total(self, request):
        return 42

    def get_publications_free(self, request):
        return 14

    def get_publications_paid(self, request):
        return 25

    def get_comments_total(self, request):
        return 1337

    def get_votes_total(self, request):
        return 1207
```

where you thus can fill in more sophisticated functions for the the `get_foo` methods.

Then we can work with:

```
class SomeView:
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        response_data = []
        if "fields" in request.query_params:
            fields = request.GET.getlist('fields')
            for field in fields:
                try:
                    _filter = CounterFilter(field)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                else:
                    response_data.append(
                        {'type': field, 'count': _filter(request)}
                    )
        return Response(response_data)
```

You of course can work with different parameters to make the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
class CounterFilters(TextChoices):
    publications_total = "publications-total"
    publications_free = "publications-free"
    publications_paid = "publications-paid"
    comments_total = "comments-total"
    votes_total = "voted-total"

calculation_functions = {
    CounterFilters.publications_total: functionA,
    CounterFilters.publications_free: functionB,
    CounterFilters.publications_paid: functionC,
    CounterFilters.comments_total: functionD,
    CounterFilters.votes_total: functionE,
}

class SomeView:

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        response_data = []
        if "fields" in request.query_params:
            fields = request.GET.getlist("fields")
            for field in fields:
                response_data.append({"type": field, "count": calculation_functions[field]()})
        return Response(response_data)
```

I'm not 100% sure if that how the dictionary of functions worked, I'm pretty sure I used it with classes, not functions.

Someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Inside `for field in fields:`

you do

```
if field == CounterFilters.publications_total:
    response_data.append({"type": CounterFilters.publications_total})
```

Which is similar to

```
If foo is True:
 return True
```

Only one of your if conditions will ever match for the current iteration so there's no need to have so many ifs, those could be changed to `if else` or `switch case` so the other conditions after a match are not checked.

In your case, because of the `If foo is True: return True` you can just use `field` without using `ifs`

Comment: Part comparing to `return True` doesn't really make sense to me, especially the last sentence.

Comment: @matszwecja in OPs question's code he doing `if field == XXXX: response_data.append({"type": XXXX, ..........})` the only reson he needs the if statements is to do one calculation or the other. That's why I say that he can just use `response_data.append({"type": field`